# Random disconnection of an USB Camera with Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: camera, opencv, usb-power, v4l2, h264

I've got a Raspberry Pi 4 with an USB2.0 camera connected through a slip ring. When I boot, there's no problem at all, but sometimes the Raspberry is unable to detect the camera while streaming (I'm streaming with OpenCV and a PyQT GUI).

Sometimes, after the disconnection (unintentionally, and not physical), the Pi detects the camera again after a short period of time, just setting it to dev/video1 instead of dev/video0. If it happens again, it's set to dev/video2 and so on.

I can recover the camera in that situation via code.
The problem is when the Pi can't detect the camera anymore, UNTIL I REBOOT, even if I don't touch anything (I don't unplug the camera, don't move the Raspberry, etc).
I'm thinking that it's a power issue, 'cause there's the 'Low Voltage Warning' almost all the time, but the fact that a reboot 'solves' my problem makes my doubt.
I say 'solves' because I have to recover the camera while the GUI is running, not in a reboot process.

I'm powering the Pi with a DC/DC converter (12V to 5V) from a AC/DC power supply (230V to 12V. This is part of an in-pipe robot project, and that's the reason of the power convertion and the slip ring.
I'm a mechanical engineer, not software, so I'm new to Raspberry, USB Cameras and all that stuff, at least at a pro level.

EDIT:
I have an specific slip ring with usb channel. It has a male usb in both sides, one is connected directly to the Pi, and the other is connected to a female-to-female adapter, where I plug my camera. This is because I didn't wanted to change the male usb of the slip ring for a female usb, to avoid human error.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: If you are using slip rings you are defeating the normal USB phased connection protocol (power first). NOTHING to do with Pi.

Comment: @Milliways that's what I was thinking, but i tested same camera with same slip ring connected to a windows pc, and it works correctly. Maybe it's the combination of both slip ring and Pi, that sometimes you dont get the enough power.
And I have an specific slip ring that has a channel for usb, it has in both sides a male usb.